# Usage of cObject EXTBASEPLUGIN without caching (USER_INT)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I wonder if it is possible to use the cObject "EXTBASEPLUGIN" (available since TYPO3 12.3) without caching (USER_INT). In the documentation, only an example with cOcject "USER" is substituted.

[Documentation EXTBASEPLUGIN](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Extbaseplugin/Index.html#id6)

In the class TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\ContentObject\ExtbasePluginContentObject the UserObjectType is taken into account, but it is not clear to me how I can ensure that it is not set to USER (ContentObjectRenderer::OBJECTTYPE_USER).

Initial state of the code:

```
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = MyExtension
    pluginName = MyPlugin
}
```

My goal is (if possible) to use the new cObject "EXTBASEPLUGIN" while maintaining the same behavior.

Comment: When you configure the plugin with ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin, leave empty the non-cacheable actions array and you'll have the USER cObject, add actions to the array and you'll have the USER_INT cObject.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, you could put it into a COA_INT - should have the same effect.

```
page.10 = COA_INT
page.10 {
  10 = EXTBASEPLUGIN
  10 {
    extensionName = MyExtension
    pluginName = MyPlugin
  }
}
```